# Como fazer a chamada de um arquivo js dentro de um arquivo php

Tags: php, javascript, eventos

Aqui o código em php (só tá faltando a tag que 'abre' o php, e a linha que eu declaro a variável evento):

```
        /* dentro do if queria trocar este alerta por um script inteiro que estaria em um arquivo externo js,
        pois a ideia é estilizar este alert centralizando na pagina, mas vi que fazendo isso iria ter
        um script js muito grande.
        ==========| então quero saber |==============
        como faço para chamar este arquivo js dentro destes if? 
        */ 
        if($evento == 1){
            echo '<script>alert("Login e senhas inválidos!");</script>';
        }
        if($evento == 2){
            echo '<script>alert("Efetue o login para poder acessar a página!");</script>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: acho que este é o problema, como tem chaves nos if, e a parte superior do código é html, acho que tá dando problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pra mim no inicio o jQuery para JS foi bem tranquilo, sugiro que você de uma olhada.
https://jquery.com e https://jqueryui.com

No seu caso eu faria:
um arquivo js separado, que iria ser carregado no final do teu html,
neste arquivo js, utilizaria o jQuery para realizar uma chamada $.ajax(), em uma rota que faça apenas a verificação de login e retorne um json com a mensagem (sem nenhum HTML nesse arquivo no caso).

```html
<!-- arquivo.html -->
<!-- adicionar em <head> (inclui o jquery e jquery ui) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- adicionar na tag <form> (id para jquery utilizar) -->
<form id="idForm"></form>

<!-- adicionar html do modal, é com um P sem mensagem mesmo, pois o ajax que irá carragar a mensagem -->
<div id="modalMensagem"><p id="mensagem"></p></div>
```

```php
<?php
//arquivo.php
$json = ['error' => ''];
//validações de script, qualquer erro coloque o erro da seguinte forma:
switch($evento) { 
   case 1: 
      $json['error'] = 'Login e senha inválidos';
      break;
   case 2:
      $json['error'] = 'Efetue o login para poder acessar a página!';
}

/* Verifique se sua string é UTF-8, caso contrario json_encode não funcionará.
 * Para saber isto teste uma string com Ç, se retornar um json_encode vazio, é porque os caracteres não são UTF8.
 * Utilize: utf8_encode() na string. $json['error'] = utf8_encode('Mensagem de erro com Ç');
 */
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //define o header como json pra que é o que o jquery espera no ajax com dataType: json
echo json_encode($json); //exibe o json no body
```

```js
//ARQUIVO.js

$(document).ready(function(){ //jQuery, execute isto após a pagina ser carregada
   $("#idForm").submit(function(event)){ //tratamento do evento submit do form com id="idForm" 
       event.preventDefault(); //informa que o evento default não ocorrerá
       var request = $.ajax({ //inicia o ajax e associa a variavel request
           url: $("#idForm").attr("action"), //pega o parametro action do form
           method: $("#idForm").attr("method"), //pega o parametro method do form
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), //serializa o form e envia como parametro
           dataType: 'json' //espera um retorno json
       });

       request.done(function(json){ //ao final da request com retorno HTTP 20X
           if (json.error != ''){ //error foi definido no php, e json é um parametro desta função
              $("#modalMensagem #mensagem").html(json.error); //adiciona a mensagem no elemento com id="mensagem" dentro do elemento com id="modalMensagem"
              $("#modalMensagem").dialog({ //exibe modalMensagem como um modal
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      Ok: function() { //aqui é o array de botões, cada botão recebe uma function referente ao seu evento click.
                          $(this).dialog("close"); //define o que o botão OK faz, neste caso fecha o modal
                      }
              });
           } else {
              document.location.href = 'novarota.php'; //caso não tenha mensagem de erros, ocorreu um (login?) com sucesso e deve ser redirecionado.
           }
       });
   }
});
```

No evento de sucesso do $.ajax(), iria inserir a mensagem de erro em alguma  ou modal feito com jQueryUi (isto já te traria um 'alert' centralizado, mas que você poderia estilizar com CSS e colocar alguns botões com eventos).

Sugiro também dar uma olhada em alguns padrões de programação que apliquem MVC e Orientação a Objetos. (para PHP veja Zend, Laravel, Yii, Slim... Os frameworks dão uma boa base).

Comment: Obrigado man, sim vou ver estes frameworks, o laravel por exemplo vou começar a estudar esta semana nas aulas de PHP para web, e o os frameworks do js (JQuery, NodeJS) vou ver um pouco depois pois só sei o básico de javascript mesmo, aí estou procurando boas video aulas (no youtube e também Udemy) pra começar de verdade no javascript, vejo que a linguagem tem muito poder.